# Created web scraping program in Python, need to save weblinks to csv and remove duplicates

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping

I have been able to successfully scrape the website and am having some trouble saving as a csv and need help to see where I have messed up. Here is my code and I have also included a snippet of my code:

```
import bs4 as BeautifulSoup
import CSV
import re
import urllib.request
from IPython.display import HTML

# Program that scraps the website for 
r= urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.census.gov/programs- 
                           surveys/popest.html').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(r,"html.parser")


for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))

with open("Giles_C996.csv","w") as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file,delimiter="/n")
    writer.writerow(Links)

Close()
```

Error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\epiph\Giles_C996 Project 2.txt", line 2, in 
import CSV
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'CSV'

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5k7kt.png)

Comment: `import csv` (not `import CSV`)

Comment: Also `"\n"` (not `"/n"`), although really you want to omit that and instead do it directly in the `for` loop, as `writer.writerow([link.get('href')])`; and omit the misspelled `Close()` (the `with` statement already closes the file).

Comment: Thank you !!  I will give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

You've incorrectly imported `csv` and `bs4` modules. Also `Close()` is incorrect. And you can use conversion to `set` to get rid of duplicates.

```
import csv
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest.html').read()    
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "html.parser")
links = set([a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True)])

with open("Giles_C996.csv", "w", newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows([link] for link in links)
```

Output is:

```
https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/cps.html
/newsroom/press-releases/2020/65-older-population-grows/65-older-population-grows-spanish.html
https://www.census.gov/businessandeconomy
https://www.census.gov/data
/programs-surveys/popest/library.html
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

You had some erroneous imports and called an undefined variable.

I'm not very familiar with iPython so I can't comment much on your use of it. And always have trouble with urllibs so I just used requests.

I included some scrap code for an alternative layout for the csv file, as well as a function which can help determine if a link is valid, and a list comprehension in case you prefer that approach.
Also opens your csv file for you.

```
import csv, re, urllib.request, os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# from IPython.display import HTML

def exists(link) -> bool:
    """
    Check if request response is 200
    """
    try:
        return 200 == requests.get(link).status_code
    except requests.exceptions.MissingSchema:
        return False
    except requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema:
        return False
    
def scrapeLinks(url):
    checked = set()
    page = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page,"html.parser")
    for a in soup.find_all('a',href=True):
        link = a['href']
        if not link in checked and exists(link):
            yield link
        checked.add(link)
        
# Program that scrapes the website for 
url = 'https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest.html'
# r = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
r = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(r,"html.parser")

# links = [
    # a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a',href=True)\
    # if exists(a['href'])
# ]

file_name = "Giles_C996.csv"
with open(file_name,"w") as csv_file:
    # writer = csv.writer(csv_file),delimiter="/n")
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    # writer.writerow(set(links)) # conversion to remove duplicates
    writer.writerow(scrapeLinks(url)) 
    # writer.writerows(enumerate(scrapeLinks(url),1))  ## if you want a 2d-indexed collection

os.startfile(file_name)

# Close()
```